# FQL search by name in ASP.NET using Facebook API is not working?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-fql

FQL search by name in ASP.NET using Facebook API is not working. But, this was working fine 5 days ago. Recently, when I look for person by name using FQL (Facebook API) in ASP.NET, it is not working.

Recently, the facebook developers team has deployed Facebook API after made some changes.

I can get response for the following FQL:

```
select name, first_name, last_name from user where uid = '1730923544'
```

I could not get response for the following FQL (but I can get empty string)

```
select name, pic_square, profile_url from user where name = 'Suresh Rajan'
```

Here is my full code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    facebook.Components.FacebookService _fb = null;

    public _Default()
    {
        _fb = new FacebookService();
        _fb.ApplicationKey = "bfeefa69afdfe81975f0d6136ace3009";
        _fb.Secret = "9b672d682e1d8befd06382953fc2615b";
        _fb.IsDesktopApplication = false;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        infobel_FacebookMethod();        
    }

    private void infobel_FacebookMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            string s = String.Empty;

            //I cannot have response for this fql ( but getting empty string )
            //s = _fb.fql.query("select name, profile_url from user where name = 'Suresh Rajan'");

            //Here I can get response 
            s = _fb.fql.query("select name, from user where uid = '1730923544'");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
                Response.Write("Empty Response");
            else
                Response.Write(str1 + " <br />");            
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Response.Write("Message = " + exp.Message + "<br />");
            Response.Write("ToString = " + exp.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

How to write FQL in ASP.NET?

Thanks

Comment: i think you are searching just in the one record... or am i wrong

Comment: maybe this help >>http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LinqToFqlAddon.aspx

Comment: But 
_fb.fql.query("select name, profile_url from user where name = 'Suresh Rajan'"); //this fql was retured response 10 days ago..

from last week only, i could not get response from facebook api ..

any ideas,,,

thanks
r.e

Comment: comeon could anyone tell me how to resovle this issue !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

when I run your FQL `select name, profile_url from user where name = 'Suresh Rajan'` I get back the following error message.

> (#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain
>   an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables
>   linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

So it appears that the name property is not a column you can have in your where clause.

However, there might be another way to get the information you're looking for, use the search command from the graph API (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Format: `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE`

Example: `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user`

So for you to play around with this go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can only query using the column name in some special cases, like this: `select name, uid from user where name = 'Sergio Garcia' AND uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`